# python 3, quadratic function

Tags: python, dictionary, default

I have to Write a python function that can solve any quadratic equation in the form: ax2 + bx + c = 0, also handle the special case when some of the coefficients are zero, I have to write the function with 3 optional keyword arguments, with the default value of 0. In this way, one can use this function with any order of coefficients as long as the quadratic term is a, the linear is b and the constant is c. Also, one can leave out coefficients if they are 0.
and I have to return a list based on the following conditions: From these coefficients, calculate every real solution and return them as a list, not longer than 2.
Return None if all the coefficients are zero, because in that case you would have infinite number of solutions.
If there is no solution or only complex ones, then return an empty list.
If there is a real root with multiplicity 2, then return a one long list.
However the problem is that I didn't know how to set the default values of a dictionary when I get an empty dictionary as an input. Thank you in advance for your help!

This is my code

```
import math
def quadratic_solve(**dictr):
    List=[]
    x1=dictr['a']
    x2=dictr['b']
    x3=dictr['c']
    delta=x1*x1-4*x2*x3
    if (x1==0 and x2==0 and x3==0):
        return None
    if (x1==0):
        List.append(-x3/x2)
        return List
    if(dictr['b']*dictr['b']-4*dictr['a']*dictr['c']<0) :
        return List
    if(x2*x2-4*x1*x3>0) :
        List.append((-x2+math.sqrt(delta))/2*x1)
        List.append((-x2-math.sqrt(delta))/2*x1)
        return List
```

Comment: yes the input has to be a dictionary, and the output as a list, any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: I think the problem is that I didn't know how to fulfill this condition:I have to write the function with 3 optional keyword arguments, with the default value of 0. In this way,one can use this function with any order of coefficients as long as the quadratic term is a, the linear is b and the constant is c. Also, one can leave out coefficients if they are 0. That's why when I enter the input {'c': -1, 'b': 1, 'a': 1},or {}, I always get this error: TypeError: quadratic_solve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'c' or TypeError: quadratic_solve() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dictr'

Answer (score 1):

You could make better use of Python's feature to reduce the amount of code (i.e. focus on the essential conditions):

```
def quadratic_solve(params):
    a,b,c = [params.get(p,0) for p in "abc"]   # get this out of the way early
    if a==0: return [] if b==0 else [-c/b]     # linear equation
    b2_4ac = b*b-4*a*c                         # part under the square root
    if b2_4ac < 0: return []                   # complex result 
    p,n = (-b+b2_4ac**0.5)/2/a, (-b-b2_4ac**0.5)/2/a # + or - square root results
    return [p] if p==n else [p,n]              # one or two solutions


quadratic_solve({'a':2,'b':3}) # [0.0, -1.5]
```

Comment: the input has to be a dictionary, not an int

Comment: Your use of `**dictr` with `dictr['a'], dictr['b']...` is exactly the same as the parameters with defaults.  This is simply standard parameter unpacking in Python so the dictionary is an unnecessary complication.

Comment: sorry, there is a mistake I forgot to correct, I should have written dictr instead of **dictr (there are 3 elements in the dictionary). However, the function I should write is tested automatically by a system, and it passes a dictionary as an input like {'c': -1, 'b': 1, 'a': 1},or {}. So I can't use dictr['a'], dictr['b'], dictr['c'] as parameters

Comment: I adjusted the example to get the parameter structure issue out of the way as early as possible in the function.  This way, the rest of the code remains legible.